# What's the differences between .ToString() and + ""

Tags: c#, string, datetime

If I have a DateTime, and I do :

```
date.Year.ToString()
```

I get the Year as String. But Also if I do

```
date.Year + ""
```

the differences is only that the second one doesnt get an exception if there isn't the Date? (which i prefeer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date.Year.ToString()
```

Won't work if date is null.

```
date.Year + ""
```

Works even if year is null as binary + operator substitutes null with a empty string.

This is what MSDN says about binary + operator concatenating two strings:

The binary + operator performs string concatenation when one or both operands are of type string. If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method inherited from type object. If ToString returns null, an empty string is substituted.

More information on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: `date.Year + ""` works even if date is null? Really? And how can a DateTime be null in the first place?

Comment: What Mark said, how is it null?  Isn't that only possible if it was declared as nullable?

Answer (score 10):

When you write `date.Year + ""` it will be compiled as a call to [`string.Concat(object, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx):

```
String.Concat(date.Year, "")
```

Internally, the `Concat` method will call `ToString` on each (non-null) object.

Both approaches will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `date` is `null`. But you said `date` is of type `DateTime`. `DateTime` is a struct and so cannot be null.

---

If `date` is of type `DateTime?` and want to return an empty string if date is null then you can use this:

```
date.HasValue ? date.Value.Year.ToString() : ""
```

Comment: Uhm, I don't think so! In the second case, If the Year is null, I don't get any error/exception. Just, it doesnt do anything...

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference if `date.Year` is not null.

In the second example the `ToString()` method is implicitly called on `date.Year`.